# maven aar transitive dependencies not recognized

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-espresso

I have two projects setup with maven. The main project includes aar maven dependencies to the support-design, support-v4, appcommpat-v7 and more libraries. The second project is an espresso test project, testing the main functionalities of the app, and including the main project as maven dependency. I need to refer to some of these support classes in my second project in order to test their functionalities. I can use jar dependencies of the main project in the espresso project without problems. Only when trying to refer to the aar classes the compiler can´t find them and tells me

> error: cannot find symbol

. I´m working with Android Studio on both projects and when I look on the project structure with its dependency explorer, the Studio tells me that the "classes root.." of the required aar libraries are "..invalid".

This is how the aar packages are included in the main project and its required plugin, which is also included in the second projects. The main project is compiling properly:

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.download.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
                <version>22.2.1</version>
                <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>

 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <release>true</release>
                    <sign>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                    </sign>
                    <proguard>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </proguard>
                    <failOnNonStandardStructure>false</failOnNonStandardStructure>
                    <androidManifestFile>
                        AndroidManifest.xml
                    </androidManifestFile>
                    <resourceDirectory>res</resourceDirectory>
                    <assetsDirectory>assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>libs
                    </nativeLibrariesDirectory>

                    <sdk>
                        <platform>22</platform>
                        <path>${sdk-path}</path>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>alignApk</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My attempt to solve the issue:
 including the dependencies as provided in the espresso project pom.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.download.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>22.2.1</version>
            <type>aar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

-> Didn´t solve the problem.

Additional requirements: I need to use maven for compiling and can´t move to gradle.

Do you have any advice ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transitive AAR dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022842/transitive-aar-dependencies-in-maven)

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot find symbol` would indicate to me that there is something wrong with your code, not the dependency management. Nevertheless I think you are describing the same problem as presented in another question: [Transitive AAR dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022842/transitive-aar-dependencies-in-maven)

The answer there is to exclude the problematic dependency from the dependency to your main project in your espresso test project and then add the same problematic dependency to espresso test project, making sure to explicitly specify the type as `aar`. So the POM for your espresso test project would have something similar to the following.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.main</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <version>22.2.1</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```